# How to merge all Midi Events from tracks?

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

Some midi files have more than 1 track.

How do I merge the events from these tracks *(in order of StartTime)* into a single array/list, using the [NAudio library](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudio/Midi)?

I want to capture all NoteOn, NoteOff, and DamperPedal events in ascending order (StartTime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAudio automatically merges the tracks when you set the `MidiFileType` property of the `MidiEventCollection` to zero.